# Can a CME user set TextOnFail value of a Component Link?

Tags: content-delivery, cme, dynamic-linking

I created a Dynamic Component Presentation (ascx) that uses Dynamic Component Linking, and everything is published fine on the Content Delivery side.

However I noticed the `TextOnFail` property of the `<tridion:ComponentLink runat="server">` web control is always "true".

Question is, what is the CME behavior that sets this value, if any?

Comment: In RTF fields this is always set to true, as the content could become "weird" if a word or two disappeared...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TextOnFail value is usually set in the TBB's.

To create a TridionLink from a dwt TBB the following code is needed:

```
<a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@" tridion:textOnFail="true" class="bottom">
```

Tridion will transform the code above into a server control (.net or java) based on your env.

In this case the textOnFail is hardcoded, But the value can be set from a variable that is available in the Package.

Comment: See http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3324C14A-13DB-4147-9773-F4B4A924D09D for a list of available link attributes in Dreamweaver templating